# Foundation 4.3.1 resize issue

Tags: jquery, css, zurb-foundation

I got a Foundation 4 question, once I resize my browser window the small columns don't align properly. Any suggestions how to fix this ?

```
<div class="row">

    <div class="large-2 small-4 columns">1111 <br/>
        <a href="#">- 1111a</a><br />
        <a href="#">- 1111b</a><br />
        <a href="#">- 1111c</a><br />
    </div>
    <div class="large-2 small-4 columns">2222<br />
    <a href="#">- 2222a</a><br />
    <a href="#">- 2222b</a><br /></div>
        <div class="large-2 small-4 columns">3333</div>
    <div class="large-2 small-4 columns">4444<br />
    <a href="#">- 4444a</a><br />
    <a href="#">- 4444b</a><br /></div>
        <div class="large-2 small-4 columns">5555</div>
        <div class="large-2 small-4 columns">6666</div>

</div>
```

[Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/x45n6ykt/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[Foundation's visibility classes](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/v/4.3.2/components/visibility.html)

problem can be solved using hide-for-small and show-for-small classes.